# add to wishlist function didn't work properly as i wanted

Tags: python, django

This add_to_wishlist return two messages and eventually get_or_create act like this. But i want if an item added first time it shows "added" and next time "already added" but it return both when i click to the button. How i checked or make a query that it return me it added firstime.

i used get_or_create method. As far as i know when there is no existence of an item it will create one and if already exits it will get or override the item. I have try it in add_to_cart and it worked perfectly.

here is the model

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user = 
    models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wished_item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.wished_item.title
```

## here  is the function

```
    @login_required
    def add_to_wishlist(request,slug):

       item = get_object_or_404(Item,slug=slug)

       wished_item,created = 
       Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(wished_item=item,
       slug = item.slug,
       user = request.user,
       )

       messages.info(request,'The item was added to your wishlist')
       wish_list_qs = Wishlist.objects.filter(user = request.user,
       slug=item.slug)
       if wish_list_qs.exists():
          messages.info(request,'The item was already in your wishlist')
          return redirect('core:product_detail',slug=slug)
```

it shows both messages .... but I want one according to the action either added the first time or added again

The item was added to your wishlist

The item was already in your wishlist

Comment: change if wish_list_qs.exists(): to if not created: and in else part add messages.info(request,'The item was added to your wishlist')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `wish_list_qs.exists()` after applying `get_or_create` method will always return `True` value.
Also when you are using `get_or_create` for `wished_item` it is futile to do

```
wish_list_qs = Wishlist.objects.filter(user = request.user, slug=item.slug)
```

and then applying `exists()` method over it.
Above statement will return you the very object you created i.e. `wished_item`.
The changes that you need to make in your code is

```
def add_to_wishlist(request,slug):

   item = get_object_or_404(Item,slug=slug)

   wished_item,created = 
   Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(wished_item=item,
   slug = item.slug,
   user = request.user,
   ) # Creating or extracting the wished item
   if created: 
       # if new wished_item created
       messages.info(request,'The item was added to your wishlist')
   else:
      # if wished_item existed previously
      messages.info(request,'The item was already in your wishlist')
   return redirect('core:product_detail',slug=slug)
```